# How to fit lego power function LED lights onto cargo train (set: 60052)

Tags: power-functions

can anyone out there explain / illustrate how to fit lego power function white LED lights on the blue cargo train (set number 60052)? We have assembled the engine but I cannot see where or how these lights fit on the engine. I have watched a couple of YouTube videos showing how to fit these on other trains, but not the cargo train. There are not any holes or compatable pieces on the engine that can take the lights - as far as I can see anyway. My son is 7 and I am no lego expert by the way.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The cargo train (60052) is not out-of-the-box able to be converted to using LED lights. The light bricks (1x1 round bricks) are fitted on the front bumper of the train with no space left for the light plugs. You would need to make modifications to the train to embed the lights - for example by mounting an additional light on top of the train, or by putting different lights on the front bumper. But you would need special transparent headlight (aka Erling) bricks for that - part [4070 or 30069](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=4070) is typically used in other train sets.

Comment: Oh and here is an example of how you could add working lights to the front of the train - but you would need to work the cables into the design somehow - http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=100657